# Python scraping JSON converting to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm very new to python and this will probably be a horrendous question, but here it goes:

I'm trying to scrape data from a particular website and have that data converted to CSV. I've managed to get a working "scraper" and save the file on my computer. However, when I try to load the JSON into python again I get all kinds of errors. I believe one of the errors is caused due to the fact that I'm adding multiple JSON arrays in one file and `json.load()` can only load a single JSON (from what I understood).

To make a long story short: Could anyone please guide me in the proper direction as to how I scrape this data and get a nice readable CSV?

Please find my code below.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import datetime
import time
import json
import csv


def grabData():
    startdate = datetime.date(2015,2,1)
    startdate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    datalist = []
    for i in range(2):

        unixtime = time.mktime(startdate.timetuple())
        print(unixtime)

        url = 'https://api.*************/34.700869,135.503755,'+str(int(unixtime))+'?units=si'
        print(url)
        webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = webURL.read()
        print(data)
        encoding = webURL.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
        json.loads(data.decode(encoding))
        datalist.append(data.decode())

        startdate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)


    text = datalist
    saveFile = open('osakatest.json','a')
    saveFile.write(str(text))
    saveFile.close()


grabData()
```

Here is a snippet of the output I got.

```
[{"latitude":34.700869,"longitude":135.503755,"timezone":"Asia/Tokyo","offset":9,"currently":{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},"hourly":{"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.94,"apparentTemperature":1.07,"dewPoint":-2.09,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":1.91,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1029.11},{"time":1422806400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.23,"windBearing":292,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.7},{"time":1422810000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.78,"dewPoint":-2.17,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.11,"windBearing":270,"visibility":14.16,"pressure":1028.52},{"time":1422813600,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.47,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.36,"windBearing":282,"visibility":15.77,"cloudCover":0.38,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422817200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.13,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.19,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.16},{"time":1422820800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.56,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.72,"windSpeed":2.32,"windBearing":301,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.21},{"time":1422824400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.55,"dewPoint":-1.82,"humidity":0.71,"windSpeed":2.28,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.95,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422828000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.97,"apparentTemperature":0.69,"dewPoint":-2.1,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.29,"windBearing":304,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},{"time":1422835200,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.28,"apparentTemperature":2.64,"dewPoint":-3.14,"humidity":0.58,"windSpeed":1.89,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.63,"cloudCover":0.74,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422838800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.95,"apparentTemperature":2.61,"dewPoint":-3.67,"humidity":0.54,"windSpeed":2.79,"windBearing":301,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.43},{"time":1422842400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.13,"apparentTemperature":3.48,"dewPoint":-3.35,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.6,"windBearing":316,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.97},{"time":1422846000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.99,"apparentTemperature":3.08,"dewPoint":-3.91,"humidity":0.49,"windSpeed":3.99,"windBearing":320,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.18},{"time":1422849600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.01,"apparentTemperature":3.01,"dewPoint":-3.74,"humidity":0.5,"windSpeed":4.17,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.79},{"time":1422853200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.94,"apparentTemperature":3.4,"dewPoint":-3.33,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.34,"windBearing":343,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.69},{"time":1422856800,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.78,"apparentTemperature":2.98,"dewPoint":-3.41,"humidity":0.52,"windSpeed":3.72,"windBearing":342,"visibility":14.71,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1026.77},{"time":1422860400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.74,"apparentTemperature":3.42,"dewPoint":-3.07,"humidity":0.53,"windSpeed":2.97,"windBearing":337,"visibility":11.72,"pressure":1026.87},{"time":1422864000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.33,"apparentTemperature":2.86,"dewPoint":-2.67,"humidity":0.56,"windSpeed":3.07,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.16},{"time":1422867600,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.43,"apparentTemperature":1.56,"dewPoint":-1.98,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.37,"windBearing":323,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.26},{"time":1422871200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.36,"apparentTemperature":1.63,"dewPoint":-1.97,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.14,"windBearing":315,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.55},{"time":1422874800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.71,"dewPoint":-1.68,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.87,"windBearing":300,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1027.77},{"time":1422878400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.27,"apparentTemperature":1.95,"dewPoint":-1.74,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.59,"windBearing":313,"visibility":15.8,"cloudCover":0.76,"pressure":1027.98},{"time":1422882000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.78,"dewPoint":-1.73,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.77,"windBearing":297,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.02},{"time":1422885600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.24,"apparentTemperature":2.03,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.46,"windBearing":296,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.12}]},"daily":{"data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","sunriseTime":1422827846,"sunsetTime":1422865697,"moonPhase":0.44,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":2.84,"temperatureMinTime":1422824400,"temperatureMax":6.13,"temperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"apparentTemperatureMin":0.47,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1422813600,"apparentTemperatureMax":3.48,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"dewPoint":-2.49,"humidity":0.62,"windSpeed":2.62,"windBearing":310,"visibility":13.45,"cloudCover":0.73,"pressure":1027.9}]},"flags":{"sources":["isd"],"isd-stations":["476490-99999","476510-99999","476630-99999","476840-99999","477500-99999","477590-99999","477610-99999","477690-99999","477700-99999","477710-99999","477720-99999","477740-99999","477760-99999","477770-99999","477790-99999","477800-99999"],"units":"si"}}]
```

Ideal CSV output:

```
time,summary,icon,precipType,temperature,apparentTemperature,dewPoint,humidity,windSpeed,windBearing,visibility,pressure,cloudCover
1422802800,Clear,clear-night,rain,2.94,1.07,-2.09,0.7,1.91,295,14.52,1029.11,
1422806400,Clear,clear-night,rain,2.88,0.65,-2.12,0.7,2.23,292,14.52,1028.7,
1422810000,Clear,clear-night,rain,2.88,0.78,-2.17,0.69,2.11,270,14.16,1028.52,
1422813600,Partly Cloudy,partly-cloudy-night,rain,2.84,0.47,-2.12,0.7,2.36,282,15.77,1028.25,0.38
```

Comment: Is there a specific output format you are expecting? There are a lot of nested dicts inside the json you are receiving.

Comment: I'm just hoping to get a readable CSV. When I take this snippet and convert it to csv on http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm (removing the square brackets) it looks great. Something like this would be nice.

Comment: I think the main problem here is how your csv file will look like. You have a lot of data in your `dict["data"]`'s key. How would you to format it ?

Comment: @David would you update your question with your new comment. Try to give a clear overview of your expected output and how it'll be organized.

Comment: @ChihebNexus Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you did the part of parsing the website and you have the final `list` which contain a `python dict`. I'll use only the final output in my solution.

So, you can try those codes. They will parse your current `list` and return a `csv`.

**PS:**

Handling a `dict` like yours and parsing it with my current codes may not output an output with the order you gave in your question.

Otherwise, you can use and modify those codes untill they fills your needs.

however, with this current solutions you can have a correct `csv`. If you found any bugs or something you can't understand in the code below, don't hesitate to leave your comment.

**Solution1: Using `pandas`:**

```
import pandas as pd 
from os import getcwd

a = [{"latitude":34.700869,"longitude":135.503755,"timezone":"Asia/Tokyo","offset":9,"currently":{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},"hourly":{"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.94,"apparentTemperature":1.07,"dewPoint":-2.09,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":1.91,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1029.11},{"time":1422806400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.23,"windBearing":292,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.7},{"time":1422810000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.78,"dewPoint":-2.17,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.11,"windBearing":270,"visibility":14.16,"pressure":1028.52},{"time":1422813600,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.47,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.36,"windBearing":282,"visibility":15.77,"cloudCover":0.38,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422817200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.13,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.19,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.16},{"time":1422820800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.56,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.72,"windSpeed":2.32,"windBearing":301,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.21},{"time":1422824400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.55,"dewPoint":-1.82,"humidity":0.71,"windSpeed":2.28,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.95,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422828000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.97,"apparentTemperature":0.69,"dewPoint":-2.1,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.29,"windBearing":304,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},{"time":1422835200,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.28,"apparentTemperature":2.64,"dewPoint":-3.14,"humidity":0.58,"windSpeed":1.89,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.63,"cloudCover":0.74,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422838800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.95,"apparentTemperature":2.61,"dewPoint":-3.67,"humidity":0.54,"windSpeed":2.79,"windBearing":301,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.43},{"time":1422842400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.13,"apparentTemperature":3.48,"dewPoint":-3.35,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.6,"windBearing":316,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.97},{"time":1422846000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.99,"apparentTemperature":3.08,"dewPoint":-3.91,"humidity":0.49,"windSpeed":3.99,"windBearing":320,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.18},{"time":1422849600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.01,"apparentTemperature":3.01,"dewPoint":-3.74,"humidity":0.5,"windSpeed":4.17,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.79},{"time":1422853200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.94,"apparentTemperature":3.4,"dewPoint":-3.33,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.34,"windBearing":343,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.69},{"time":1422856800,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.78,"apparentTemperature":2.98,"dewPoint":-3.41,"humidity":0.52,"windSpeed":3.72,"windBearing":342,"visibility":14.71,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1026.77},{"time":1422860400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.74,"apparentTemperature":3.42,"dewPoint":-3.07,"humidity":0.53,"windSpeed":2.97,"windBearing":337,"visibility":11.72,"pressure":1026.87},{"time":1422864000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.33,"apparentTemperature":2.86,"dewPoint":-2.67,"humidity":0.56,"windSpeed":3.07,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.16},{"time":1422867600,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.43,"apparentTemperature":1.56,"dewPoint":-1.98,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.37,"windBearing":323,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.26},{"time":1422871200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.36,"apparentTemperature":1.63,"dewPoint":-1.97,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.14,"windBearing":315,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.55},{"time":1422874800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.71,"dewPoint":-1.68,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.87,"windBearing":300,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1027.77},{"time":1422878400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.27,"apparentTemperature":1.95,"dewPoint":-1.74,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.59,"windBearing":313,"visibility":15.8,"cloudCover":0.76,"pressure":1027.98},{"time":1422882000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.78,"dewPoint":-1.73,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.77,"windBearing":297,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.02},{"time":1422885600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.24,"apparentTemperature":2.03,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.46,"windBearing":296,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.12}]},"daily":{"data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","sunriseTime":1422827846,"sunsetTime":1422865697,"moonPhase":0.44,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":2.84,"temperatureMinTime":1422824400,"temperatureMax":6.13,"temperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"apparentTemperatureMin":0.47,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1422813600,"apparentTemperatureMax":3.48,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"dewPoint":-2.49,"humidity":0.62,"windSpeed":2.62,"windBearing":310,"visibility":13.45,"cloudCover":0.73,"pressure":1027.9}]},"flags":{"sources":["isd"],"isd-stations":["476490-99999","476510-99999","476630-99999","476840-99999","477500-99999","477590-99999","477610-99999","477690-99999","477700-99999","477710-99999","477720-99999","477740-99999","477760-99999","477770-99999","477790-99999","477800-99999"],"units":"si"}}]

WORKING_DIRECTORY = getcwd()

def to_csv(a, key, path = WORKING_DIRECTORY, file_name = "new_file.csv"):
    full_path = path + '/' + file_name
    # Only those two keys are supported for this piece of code
    # More work and debugging for the other keys is needed
    if key == "hourly" or key == "daily":
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a[key]["data"]).to_csv(full_path)
    else:
        raise Exception("Those keys are not supported yet!")

for k in a:
    to_csv(k, "hourly", file_name="hourly.csv")
    to_csv(k, "daily", file_name="daily.csv" )
```

**Solution2: Doing the job manually:** (Not a good way but you can learn how you can face this kind of problems without using an external modules.)

```
# This code will use OrderedDict 
# In order to maintain the order of the dicts
from collections import OrderedDict

a = [{"latitude":34.700869,"longitude":135.503755,"timezone":"Asia/Tokyo","offset":9,"currently":{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},"hourly":{"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.94,"apparentTemperature":1.07,"dewPoint":-2.09,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":1.91,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1029.11},{"time":1422806400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.23,"windBearing":292,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.7},{"time":1422810000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.78,"dewPoint":-2.17,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.11,"windBearing":270,"visibility":14.16,"pressure":1028.52},{"time":1422813600,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.47,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.36,"windBearing":282,"visibility":15.77,"cloudCover":0.38,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422817200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.13,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.19,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.16},{"time":1422820800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.56,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.72,"windSpeed":2.32,"windBearing":301,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.21},{"time":1422824400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.55,"dewPoint":-1.82,"humidity":0.71,"windSpeed":2.28,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.95,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422828000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.97,"apparentTemperature":0.69,"dewPoint":-2.1,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.29,"windBearing":304,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},{"time":1422835200,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.28,"apparentTemperature":2.64,"dewPoint":-3.14,"humidity":0.58,"windSpeed":1.89,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.63,"cloudCover":0.74,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422838800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.95,"apparentTemperature":2.61,"dewPoint":-3.67,"humidity":0.54,"windSpeed":2.79,"windBearing":301,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.43},{"time":1422842400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.13,"apparentTemperature":3.48,"dewPoint":-3.35,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.6,"windBearing":316,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.97},{"time":1422846000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.99,"apparentTemperature":3.08,"dewPoint":-3.91,"humidity":0.49,"windSpeed":3.99,"windBearing":320,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.18},{"time":1422849600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.01,"apparentTemperature":3.01,"dewPoint":-3.74,"humidity":0.5,"windSpeed":4.17,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.79},{"time":1422853200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.94,"apparentTemperature":3.4,"dewPoint":-3.33,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.34,"windBearing":343,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.69},{"time":1422856800,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.78,"apparentTemperature":2.98,"dewPoint":-3.41,"humidity":0.52,"windSpeed":3.72,"windBearing":342,"visibility":14.71,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1026.77},{"time":1422860400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.74,"apparentTemperature":3.42,"dewPoint":-3.07,"humidity":0.53,"windSpeed":2.97,"windBearing":337,"visibility":11.72,"pressure":1026.87},{"time":1422864000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.33,"apparentTemperature":2.86,"dewPoint":-2.67,"humidity":0.56,"windSpeed":3.07,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.16},{"time":1422867600,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.43,"apparentTemperature":1.56,"dewPoint":-1.98,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.37,"windBearing":323,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.26},{"time":1422871200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.36,"apparentTemperature":1.63,"dewPoint":-1.97,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.14,"windBearing":315,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.55},{"time":1422874800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.71,"dewPoint":-1.68,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.87,"windBearing":300,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1027.77},{"time":1422878400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.27,"apparentTemperature":1.95,"dewPoint":-1.74,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.59,"windBearing":313,"visibility":15.8,"cloudCover":0.76,"pressure":1027.98},{"time":1422882000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.78,"dewPoint":-1.73,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.77,"windBearing":297,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.02},{"time":1422885600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.24,"apparentTemperature":2.03,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.46,"windBearing":296,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.12}]},"daily":{"data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","sunriseTime":1422827846,"sunsetTime":1422865697,"moonPhase":0.44,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":2.84,"temperatureMinTime":1422824400,"temperatureMax":6.13,"temperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"apparentTemperatureMin":0.47,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1422813600,"apparentTemperatureMax":3.48,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"dewPoint":-2.49,"humidity":0.62,"windSpeed":2.62,"windBearing":310,"visibility":13.45,"cloudCover":0.73,"pressure":1027.9}]},"flags":{"sources":["isd"],"isd-stations":["476490-99999","476510-99999","476630-99999","476840-99999","477500-99999","477590-99999","477610-99999","477690-99999","477700-99999","477710-99999","477720-99999","477740-99999","477760-99999","477770-99999","477790-99999","477800-99999"],"units":"si"}}]


def get_data(a, key):

    # This part of code for the complex parts of the dict
    # For: the key 'hourly' and 'daily'
    data, final = [], ''
    if key == 'daily' or key == 'hourly':
        data = [OrderedDict(k) for k in a[key]["data"]]
        # Note here that your JSON don't have the same numbers of keys in their inside dicts
        # This is why this code fetch the max dict's items
        # For example: The key 'cloudCover' isn't present in all the 
        # dicts with key 'hourly' of the original JSON
        max_topic = max(map(lambda x: x.keys(), data), key=lambda x: len(x))
        topic = ','.join(max_topic) + '\n'
        for k in data:
            for j in max_topic:
                try:
                    final += str(k[j]) +', '
                except KeyError:
                    # if the keys isn't found add an empty string
                    final += ' ,' 
            final += '\n'

    # This part for the key 'flags'
    elif key == 'flags':
        data = a[key]
        topic = "{0},{1},{2}\n".format("isd-stations", "sources", "units")
        sub_final = ',{0},{1}\n'.format(''.join(a[key]['sources']), a[key]['units'])
        final = sub_final + ',\n'.join(a[key]["isd-stations"])

    elif key == 'currently':
        data = OrderedDict(a[key])
        topic = ','.join(a[key].keys()) + '\n'
        final = ','.join(map(str, a[key].values()))

    # This part for the other keys like: 'offset'
    # If there will be another key
    # This code will throw an exception 'KeyError'
    else:
        topic = key + '\n'
        final = str(a[key]) + '\n'

    return topic, final

def write_to_csv(a, key, file_name="new_file.csv"):
    topic, data = get_data(a, key)
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write("{0}{1}".format(topic, ''.join(data)))
        # An empty line used if you will run this code multiple times
        # and you'll append your data in a single file
        # This will seperate your formated data for better visualisation
        f.write("\n")


for k in a:
    write_to_csv(k, "hourly", "hourly.csv")
    write_to_csv(k, "daily", "daily.csv")
    write_to_csv(k, "flags", "flags.csv")
```

Output:

**hourly.csv**

```
temperature,windBearing,cloudCover,icon,precipType,summary,humidity,dewPoint,time,pressure,visibility,windSpeed,apparentTemperature
2.94, 295,  ,clear-night, rain, Clear, 0.7, -2.09, 1422802800, 1029.11, 14.52, 1.91, 1.07, 
2.88, 292,  ,clear-night, rain, Clear, 0.7, -2.12, 1422806400, 1028.7, 14.52, 2.23, 0.65, 
2.88, 270,  ,clear-night, rain, Clear, 0.69, -2.17, 1422810000, 1028.52, 14.16, 2.11, 0.78, 
2.84, 282, 0.38, partly-cloudy-night, rain, Partly Cloudy, 0.7, -2.12, 1422813600, 1028.25, 15.77, 2.36, 0.47, 
...
```

**daily.csv**

```
windBearing,apparentTemperatureMax,summary,apparentTemperatureMin,apparentTemperatureMaxTime,temperatureMaxTime,apparentTemperatureMinTime,windSpeed,pressure,temperatureMin,sunsetTime,icon,cloudCover,moonPhase,time,temperatureMinTime,visibility,dewPoint,sunriseTime,precipType,humidity,temperatureMax
310, 3.48, Clear throughout the day., 0.47, 1422842400, 1422842400, 1422813600, 2.62, 1027.9, 2.84, 1422865697, clear-day, 0.73, 0.44, 1422802800, 1422824400, 13.45, -2.49, 1422827846, rain, 0.62, 6.13,
...
```

**flags.csv**

```
isd-stations,sources,units
,isd,si
476490-99999,
476510-99999,
476630-99999,
476840-99999,
...
```

Comment: I am very grateful for all the people that take time to help people like me out. Hope I can return the favor to other people some day.

Comment: You're welcome. And i'm glad that my answer solves your problem. Don't hesitate to come again to improve, modify or correct this answer or if you have a better solution, please come an share it with us. We learn from each others and this is why coding is a piece of art and fun. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to scrape the data from the url and get it into a variable.

The easiest way to convert a `json` to `csv` is to use the almighty `pandas` library. 
You can put this into a `pandas` data frame and then convert it directly to a `csv`.

Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

json_obj = [{"latitude":34.700869,"longitude":135.503755,"timezone":"Asia/Tokyo","offset":9,"currently":{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},"hourly":{"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.94,"apparentTemperature":1.07,"dewPoint":-2.09,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":1.91,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1029.11},{"time":1422806400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.23,"windBearing":292,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.7},{"time":1422810000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.78,"dewPoint":-2.17,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.11,"windBearing":270,"visibility":14.16,"pressure":1028.52},{"time":1422813600,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.47,"dewPoint":-2.12,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.36,"windBearing":282,"visibility":15.77,"cloudCover":0.38,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422817200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.65,"dewPoint":-2.13,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.19,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.16},{"time":1422820800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.88,"apparentTemperature":0.56,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.72,"windSpeed":2.32,"windBearing":301,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.21},{"time":1422824400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.84,"apparentTemperature":0.55,"dewPoint":-1.82,"humidity":0.71,"windSpeed":2.28,"windBearing":295,"visibility":14.95,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1028.25},{"time":1422828000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":2.97,"apparentTemperature":0.69,"dewPoint":-2.1,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.29,"windBearing":304,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422831600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":3.51,"apparentTemperature":1.37,"dewPoint":-2.53,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.24,"windBearing":294,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.66},{"time":1422835200,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.28,"apparentTemperature":2.64,"dewPoint":-3.14,"humidity":0.58,"windSpeed":1.89,"windBearing":285,"visibility":14.63,"cloudCover":0.74,"pressure":1028.55},{"time":1422838800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.95,"apparentTemperature":2.61,"dewPoint":-3.67,"humidity":0.54,"windSpeed":2.79,"windBearing":301,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1028.43},{"time":1422842400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.13,"apparentTemperature":3.48,"dewPoint":-3.35,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.6,"windBearing":316,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.97},{"time":1422846000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.99,"apparentTemperature":3.08,"dewPoint":-3.91,"humidity":0.49,"windSpeed":3.99,"windBearing":320,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.18},{"time":1422849600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":6.01,"apparentTemperature":3.01,"dewPoint":-3.74,"humidity":0.5,"windSpeed":4.17,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.79},{"time":1422853200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.94,"apparentTemperature":3.4,"dewPoint":-3.33,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":3.34,"windBearing":343,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1026.69},{"time":1422856800,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.78,"apparentTemperature":2.98,"dewPoint":-3.41,"humidity":0.52,"windSpeed":3.72,"windBearing":342,"visibility":14.71,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1026.77},{"time":1422860400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.74,"apparentTemperature":3.42,"dewPoint":-3.07,"humidity":0.53,"windSpeed":2.97,"windBearing":337,"visibility":11.72,"pressure":1026.87},{"time":1422864000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipType":"rain","temperature":5.33,"apparentTemperature":2.86,"dewPoint":-2.67,"humidity":0.56,"windSpeed":3.07,"windBearing":329,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.16},{"time":1422867600,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.43,"apparentTemperature":1.56,"dewPoint":-1.98,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.37,"windBearing":323,"visibility":14.45,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1027.26},{"time":1422871200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.36,"apparentTemperature":1.63,"dewPoint":-1.97,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":3.14,"windBearing":315,"visibility":11.76,"pressure":1027.55},{"time":1422874800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.71,"dewPoint":-1.68,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.87,"windBearing":300,"visibility":12.41,"pressure":1027.77},{"time":1422878400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.27,"apparentTemperature":1.95,"dewPoint":-1.74,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.59,"windBearing":313,"visibility":15.8,"cloudCover":0.76,"pressure":1027.98},{"time":1422882000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.25,"apparentTemperature":1.78,"dewPoint":-1.73,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.77,"windBearing":297,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.02},{"time":1422885600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipType":"rain","temperature":4.24,"apparentTemperature":2.03,"dewPoint":-1.72,"humidity":0.65,"windSpeed":2.46,"windBearing":296,"visibility":14.52,"pressure":1028.12}]},"daily":{"data":[{"time":1422802800,"summary":"Clear throughout the day.","icon":"clear-day","sunriseTime":1422827846,"sunsetTime":1422865697,"moonPhase":0.44,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":2.84,"temperatureMinTime":1422824400,"temperatureMax":6.13,"temperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"apparentTemperatureMin":0.47,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1422813600,"apparentTemperatureMax":3.48,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1422842400,"dewPoint":-2.49,"humidity":0.62,"windSpeed":2.62,"windBearing":310,"visibility":13.45,"cloudCover":0.73,"pressure":1027.9}]},"flags":{"sources":["isd"],"isd-stations":["476490-99999","476510-99999","476630-99999","476840-99999","477500-99999","477590-99999","477610-99999","477690-99999","477700-99999","477710-99999","477720-99999","477740-99999","477760-99999","477770-99999","477790-99999","477800-99999"],"units":"si"}}]

pd.DataFrame(json_obj[0]).to_csv("/tmp/test.csv")
```